# How do I execute one line of code after anohter in Angular/Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am a newbie to Angular. Here I am trying to run the following lines of code sequentially in typescript. How do I do it?

```
item:any;
ngOninit() {
   this.paramID = this.http.get(url). // Step 1
                  subscribe(data => {
                  console.log(data); // Step 2
                  this.item = data;
                  return data;
                  });

  console.log(this.item); // Step 3, wait till this.item is initialized
  // Another Async request's response // Step 4
  // Some last line of code // Step 5
}
```

So, finally it should wait for any subsequent step, before current step is completed.

Expected order is : 
Step 1 -> Step 2 -> Step 3 -> Step 4 -> Step 5 all in sequence

Comment: can you share the implementation of the functions, stackblitz would be great

Comment: Are the implementations important? I just want sequential execution of the lines of code. What it does is irrelevant.

Comment: of course that is important, till now these are synchronous, if you are doing any http-like thing inside those it will be async

Comment: These three lines of code will execute one after the other. You don't have anything to do. There is no asynchrony at all in this code.

Comment: For clarity, I believe what @Borg1903 is saying is that they would like this to execute in a chain. That they do not want the second line to run until the 1st has finished and to run the 3rd after the 2nd has finished.

Comment: @DanGorman Yes! Like I said, These are just 3 random lines of code. If they are asynchronous lines, how do I execute them one after the other? Because the snapshot.paramMap might take some time to execute and hence my_func() might end up running before it.

Comment: Isn't `get` synchronous though? It might help if you used an example with a clearer problem.

Comment: @Borg1903 can you share minimum reproducing problem, Stackblitz would be great, as i mentioned earlier.
Currently, you are asking a solution for a problem without clarifying it

Comment: *If they are asynchronous lines*: they are not. There is no asynchrony at all in these lines of code. So, if you have a concrete problem with these lines of code, tell precisely what the problem is.

Comment: Now there is asynchrony. Just move the lines 3, 4, 5 **inside** the callback passed to subscribe, right after the line `this.item = data;`. Note that the `return data` doesn't serve any purpose. And that subscribe() does not return a param ID. Also note that since step 4 and step 5 are just comments, they won't be executed. If you have a question about **concrete** lines of code, post those lines of code, not comments.

Comment: [This article may be of help.](https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293). It is hard to tell how to help you with your problem because you aren't providing concrete coding examples of the problem. The solution will be specific to whatever you are doing in these placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible your snapshot is not loaded yet when ngOnInit is running. I would suggest subscribing to the activated route params then running any other code after it is updated:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.subscribeToRouteParams()
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
   this.querySub.unsubscribe()
}

private subscribeToRouteParams(): void {
   this.querySub = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => this.updateId(data));
}

private updateId(data: params): void {
    this.paramId = data.id
    this.anyOtherFunctionalityDependentOnTheId()
}
```

edit: I'm making the assumption that paramId is undefined in your posted code. If that's not the case then you don't need to do anything as that code will run sequentially

Answer (score -2):

You can use forkjoin, not sure how you wanted it but its an option.

https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61

Comment: Or you can call one function within the other